# Ocultar texto quando não couber dentro da div

Tags: html, css, css3

Bom tenho uma div com a seguinte class `c-txt`, reparem que quando o texto não cabe dentro dela, o texto e resumido com três pontos (...).

Preciso fazer isso com a div `txt` para evitar a quebra nos botões.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Tentei fazer assim:

```
.container-footer .txt {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Porém os 3 pontos não aparecem. Segue meu código.

Uma alternativa poderia ser usar o jQuery?

```css
.container {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .linha {
    border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.container-head {
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    height: 65px;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 65px;
    display: flex;
}
.container-head .c-ico {
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 60px;
}
.container-head .c-ico .material-icons {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container-head .c-txt {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-bt {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 140px;
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
}
.container-head .c-menu {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu ul {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.container-body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container-body .notification {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body .row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.container-body .tab-content {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.container-body .tabs {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body-scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 319px;
    text-align: left;
}
.container-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.container-footer button {
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: 0;
    height: 35px;
    min-width: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
}
.container-footer .txt {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    
}
/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

    .container.w50 {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .container.w50 {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Container Button -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Container Head -->
            <div class="container-head">
                <div class="c-ico"></div>
                <div class="c-txt">TÍTULO CONTAINER BUTTON orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida et elit et mattis. </div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Container Footer -->
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1 orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida et elit et mattis. orem ipsum dolor sit.
                </div>
                <button type='button'>OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-green-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-red-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-blue-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-yellow-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa possível duplicata não aborda a raiz do problema. O autor da pergunta já faz uso de text-overflow: ellipsis; A solução,  é frisar o uso de  white-space: nowrap; em conjunto, o que em nenhum post isto foi dito.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo ambos respostas mostram o uso de `white-space: nowrap;`, se for para frisar todo detalhe que as pessoas esquecerem teria que reabrir umas 10.000 perguntas fechadas e só pra constar a pergunta ainda não foi fechada, talvez não seja dup mesmo, por isto está escrito "possivel duplicata".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sem esse white-space: nowrap; o text-overflow: ellipsis não funciona de jeito nenhum, esse detalhe, creio eu, não poderia ser esquecido jamais! Vou até frisar isso na minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Trecho modificado :

> .container-footer .txt{
>
> white-space: nowrap;
>
> overflow: hidden;
>
> text-overflow: ellipsis;
>
> }

**Sem white-space: nowrap;** que é a propriedade que define o comportamento das quebras de linha, a propriedade text-overflow: ellipsis não funciona. white-space: nowrap – não deixa quebrar linha de jeito nenhum.

Essa propriedade do CSS  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` não força um estouro para que ele ocorra. Para que isso aconteça, é necessário que o autor utilize algumas propriedades adicionais no elemento, como setar a propriedade overflow para hidden.  [**Leia mais aqui**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Também tive que alterar a margem superior do botão para  `margin-top: -26px;`

```css
.container {
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
width: 95%;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container table {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .linha {
border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.container-head {
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
height: 65px;
background: #000;
line-height: 65px;
display: flex;
}
.container-head .c-ico {
width: 5%;
min-width: 60px;
}
.container-head .c-ico .material-icons {
padding: 20px;
}
.container-head .c-txt {
width: 75%;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-bt {
width: 20%;
min-width: 140px;
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
margin-top: 12px;
margin-right: 20px;
border: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 42px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
}
.container-head .c-menu {
width: 20%;
min-width: 100px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu {
z-index: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
max-width: 24px;
float: right;
margin-right: 40px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu ul {
margin-top: -5px;
}
.container-body {
padding: 20px;
}
.container-body .notification {
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body .row {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
.container-body .tab-content {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
}
.container-body .tabs {
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body-scroll {
overflow: auto;
height: 319px;
text-align: left;
}
.container-footer {
border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
height: 50px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.container-footer button {
margin-top: -26px;
border: 0;
height: 35px;
min-width: 36px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
}

.container-footer .txt{
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
margin-top: 15px;
width: 90%;
}

/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

.container.w50 {
    width: 80%;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.container.w50 {
    width: 95%;
}
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

            <!-- Container Head -->
            <div class="container-head">
                <div class="c-ico"></div>
                <div class="c-txt">TÍTULO CONTAINER BUTTON orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida et elit et mattis. </div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Container Footer -->
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1 orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum gravida et elit et mattis. orem ipsum dolor sit.
                </div>
                <button type='button'>OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-green-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-red-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-blue-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="txt">
                    TEXTO 1
                </div>
                <button type='button' class="bg-yellow-2-houve">OK</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo de como fica com tela reduzida na largura

[image: tela reduzida na largura]

Comment: Bom é quase isso, o problema é que o texto esta sobre o botão. Os três pontos tem que aparecer antes do botão.

Comment: uai, simples,veja lá na resposta editada cloquei width: 90%; mas vc ajuste a sua vontade.

Comment: Ficou legal, mas quando o botão e maior e a tela fica muito pequena o texto ainda sobrepõem o botão, tem alguma forma de fazer um calculo? Com jQuery ou css. De alguma forma para ele alterar o `width` para menor de 90% caso não caiba.

Comment: Já experimentou reduzir mais, para 80%?

Comment: Sim, porém se eu escrever um texto maior no botão ele vai ficar maior, e o texto sobrepõem.

Comment: Melhor fazer outra pergunta postando a nova situação para que essa não fique confusa.

Comment: Se puder colocar o link para nova pergunta, para eu poder acompanhar.

Comment: @LéoCunha até agora não vi o autor fazer nova pergunta com a nova situação. Se eu achar a nova pergunta te aviso

Comment: Ok, Obrigado @LeoCaracciolo.

Comment: @LéoCunha ele chegou a uma solução nessa mesma pergunta, não abriu outra não

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, obrigado, só fiquei sem saber como ele resolveu. rs

Answer (score 1):

> Só faltou especificar o tamanho da div (.container-footer .txt")

coloca assim:

```
.container-footer .txt {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
 width: 75%;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Comment: o tamanho da div não importa, o que importa é quando redimensiona a janela do navegador, aí que vai aparecer os .... quando a largura da tela for menor que a do texto

Comment: Léo cunha, da sua forma ficou bom, porém se o botão for maior acaba ocorrendo uma quebra de linha.

Answer (score 0):

Bom estou respondendo minha própria pergunta, pois com base nas respostas anteriores eu consegui chegar no resultado que eu queria.

```css
.container {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.container table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .linha {
    border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
}
.container-head {
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    height: 65px;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 65px;
    display: flex;
}
.container-head .c-ico {
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 60px;
}
.container-head .c-ico .material-icons {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container-head .c-txt, .container-footer .c-txt {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container-head .c-bt, .container-footer .c-bt {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 140px;
}
.container-head .c-bt button {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
}
.container-head .c-menu {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.container-head .c-menu .overflow-menu ul {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.container-body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.container-body .notification {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body .row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.container-body .tab-content {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.container-body .tabs {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
.container-body-scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 319px;
    text-align: left;
}
.container-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}
.container-footer .c-txt {
    width: 80%;
}
.container-footer button {
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: 0;
    height: 35px;
    min-width: 36px;
    max-width: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
}
/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

    .container.w50 {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .container.w50 {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

```html
 <!-- Container Head -->
            <div class="container-head">
                <div class="c-ico"></div>
                <div class="c-txt">TÍTULO CONTAINER BUTTON</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>FINALIZAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Container Footer -->
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="c-txt">TEXTO 1 f s fg dsg dfgdsg fgds g dsg sd g dfsg dfs g dfsgds</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>OdfsgdsfK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="c-txt">TEXTO 1</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="c-txt">TEXTO 1</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="c-txt">TEXTO 1</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-footer">
                <div class="c-txt">TEXTO 1</div>
                <div class="c-bt">
                    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```